# Append nodes to document fragment along with break tags

Tags: javascript, for-loop, contenteditable, documentfragment

Strange situation, couldn't find a solution online.  I have some `innerHTML` inside a `contentEditable` area which I'm trying to add to a document fragment...and preserve the format, which includes break tags.  When I do this:

```
var d = document.createDocumentFragment();
var content = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(content);
//this logs (img, br, span, br, img, br, span) ~ I shortened the output to just tags
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    (function(iCopy) {
        d.appendChild(content[iCopy]);
    })(i);
}
console.log(d);
```

The last log returns (img, span, img, span).  Why does the loop not recognize break tags and what can I do to add them to my document fragment?

When I log without appending anything to the fragment like so:

```
var content = document.querySelector('#content');
for (var i = 0; i < content.children.length; i++) {
    console.log(content.children[i].tagName);
    //d.appendChild(content.children[i]);
}
```

I get "img, br, span, br, img, br, span".  As soon as I uncomment `appendChild`, the breaks disappear.  Why??

My solution:

```
var d = document.createDocumentFragment();
var content = document.querySelector('#content');
while (content.children.length > 0) {
    d.appendChild(content.children[0]);
}
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add elements to the `documentFragment`, you're removing them from the DOM, which makes the collection you're iterating update and re-index.

If the `<br>` elements are every other one, then naturally, they'll be the ones skipped because of the re-indexing.

To fix it, iterate in reverse so that you're going away from the re-indexing instead of toward it.

```
for (var i = content.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    d.appendChild(content[i]);
}
```

FYI, I removed the immediately invoked function, because it's pointless.

---

You should be aware that this flattens all DOM nodes into the list. If there are nested nodes, they'll no longer be nested.

Comment: I just did `while (content.children.length > 0) {d.appendChild(content.children[0]);}`.  That makes sense now that I understand that it is getting re-indexed